# TFS 2013 Unit Tests In Parallel

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, parallel-processing

Can TFS 2013 Run Unit Tests In Parallel.

Its seems the parallelTestCount="0" will not work if you update the Build Process Template to version 12.xmal from version 11.xmal

Can you run unit tests with multiple agents to achieve this?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on multiple agents in parallel, I don't think   parellelTestCount would work. See more information [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/12/30/run-unit-tests-in-parallel-using-visual-studio-2010/) in the comments section.